# How to backup sqlite db outside of the APP and restore when user install the app

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I am trying to backup data from sqlite and when user delete and reinstall the app , backup data will be restore for user . backup process will run on the background. I tried to save in External File Dir
**getExternalFilesDir** .I can save successfully and restore successfully. But When I test it on latest android phone, all data are gone when app is deleted. Is there any way to save data outside of the app?